# Jinja not importing expression data from app

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to embed data from a database, I am inserting the data as a list but it is not showing on the webpage.
[image]

```
@user.route('/book-lesson/<int:id>', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def get_book_lesson(id): 

    tutor = TutorList.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
    data = []
    info = {
        'tutor_id': id,
        'first_name': tutor.first_name,
        'last_name': tutor.last_name,
    }
    data.append(info)
    print(data)
    return render_template('user/book_lecture.html', username=current_user.username, tutor=data)
```

```
      <h2 class="title">Book a lesson</h2>
      <div class="top_line"></div>
      <div class="booking_inner_screen">
          <div class="tutor_name"><h3>Private lesson with {{ tutor.first_name }} {{ tutor.last_name }}</h3></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning a list, return the info dict. Change the return render ... from

```
tutor = data
```

to

```
tutor = info
```

and try again. If you really want to use the list which is only needed if list length > 1 in your case, you need to add a for loop in your template, see  for instance https://ttl255.com/jinja2-tutorial-part-2-loops-and-conditionals/#loops.